# I am trying to open SpreadsheetView using ControlsFX

Tags: javafx, java-11, controlsfx

I'm trying to load a SpreadsheetView to a pane but whenever I try to load it throws an exception that I cannot identify.
I just used the sample code from de doc.
Thank you in advance and sorry if this is too trivial.
I'm running on java 11.0.1
using javafx 11 runtime.
I added this option to the jvm

--add-exports
 javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls

and I'm using maven.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:465)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1380)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$12(ContextMenuContent.java:1333)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar impl.org.controlsfx.spreadsheet.GridVirtualFlow.getVbar()'
    at org.controlsfx.controls/impl.org.controlsfx.spreadsheet.GridVirtualFlow.<init>(GridVirtualFlow.java:106)
    at org.controlsfx.controls/impl.org.controlsfx.spreadsheet.GridViewSkin.createVirtualFlow(GridViewSkin.java:867)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualContainerBase.<init>(VirtualContainerBase.java:70)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkinBase.<init>(TableViewSkinBase.java:257)
    at org.controlsfx.controls/impl.org.controlsfx.spreadsheet.GridViewSkin.<init>(GridViewSkin.java:188)
    at org.controlsfx.controls/impl.org.controlsfx.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetGridView.createDefaultSkin(SpreadsheetGridView.java:67)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:897)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.access$000(Control.java:83)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1397)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.access$400(Parent.java:79)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:63)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSS(ControlHelper.java:55)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:886)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.access$000(Control.java:83)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1397)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.access$400(Parent.java:79)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9529)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:569)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1745)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$2.preferredSize(Scene.java:393)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.preferredSize(SceneHelper.java:66)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1086)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1174)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1189)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:273)
    at com.leboroz/com.leboroz.Controller.handleVistaPrevia(Controller.java:315)
    ... 54 more
```

Comment: the method was added in fx12 - more specifically, its scope changed from package to protected. Either upgrade your fx or downgrade the controlsfx version

Comment: I upgrated to 12 and added some flags to the jvm options and It finally opens.